# Primary Key or Composite Key - performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a question regarding the primary key or composite key.

Database: SQL Server

The following occurs, I have to import data from another system.
One of the tables has a triple key (company, code and year). I'll call it Sale.
And there is, for example, a table that has a quadruple key (company, code, year and item) that I will call SaleItem.

I will have to import this information but I thought about not creating a triple, quadruple key in my bank, but creating a uniqueidentifier (primary) key from the key, but I have to store this information separately.

Sale:

```
SaleId Uniqueidentifier (Company: 1 byte, Code: 8 bytes, Year: 2 bytes, 5 bytes 0) PK
Company byte
Code bigint
Year byte
...
```

In the SaleItem table I thought of also creating a primary key

```
SaleItemId Uniqueidentifier(Company: 1 byte, Code: 8 bytes, Year: 2 bytes, Item: 2 bytes, 3 bytes 0) PK
SaleId Uniqueidentifier (Company: 1 byte, Code: 8 bytes, Year: 2 bytes, 5 bytes 0) FK
Item tinyint
...
```

Or in that same table make a composite key of SaleId and Item

```
SaleId Uniqueidentifier (Company: 1 byte, Code: 8 bytes, Year: 2 bytes, 5 bytes 0) PK FK
Item tinyint PK
...
```

There will also be tables referencing SaleItem.

What would be better all composed? All primary key? Or?

Comment: Do you need a `Uniqueidentifier`? Would an `int` or even `bigint` not be appropriate?

Comment: You still need separate columns to enforce referential integrity. If you want to avoid an unwieldly composite key for relationships, introduce a surrogate key in addition to the composite key.

Comment: Simple Key and INTEGER

Comment: The auto increment int key didn't work for my case because I would have to query the table to find the key to reference. Creating my own uniqueidentifier key from the composite keys avoids this query on the table and for timing reasons (one import can occur before the other).

Comment: Each table matters at different times and its counterpart may or may not exist. Int being an auto increment primary key would not work for this case. It would be a FK without validation.

Comment: And how would a `uniqueidentifier` be any different? It's a 16 byte value that would be auto generated, as opposed to an (always ascending) integer value.

Comment: It would not be generated randomly but from the composite key information. SaleId Uniqueidentifier (Company: 1 byte, Code: 8 bytes, Year: 2 bytes, 5 bytes 0 = 16 bytes)

Comment: I think some of the confusion here is you are saying uniqueidentifier which is a sql server datatype but that isn't what you really mean. You are generating a unique value based on the external data. I would suggest that you do not want to munge these values together as that violates 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. If the data has a composite key then you need to import that data with those columns. You could use an identity as your primary key if you wanted and add a unique constraint to the three or four columns that make up the external key.

Comment: @SeanLange It turns out that SaleItem can be imported before Sale. So either I would have to leave the triple key (FK) in SaleItem or use a unique key (FK) that is unique but that I know when importing Sale.
If not, I would have to create the record in Sale to generate the unique key with all the other fields null, which would end up harming the validation of the fields. Or would have to separate in one more table taking up more space.

So my question still remains regarding performance. It would be better to create a uniqueidentifier primary key than to use a triple composite key.

Comment: This is impossible to answer. There are too many factors to make a blanket statement that one approach would be more performant than the other. The best way would be for you try out both approaches in a test environment and determine which is better for your needs.

Comment: Coming from someone who had a table with 4 keys and after writing large number of joins with large number of other tables a large number of times i think you'll thank yourself by creating a lookup table with INT id, int company, int item, int year, int code, and only saving the ID into all tables. The downside is you need to lookup to do aggregations and inserts. This might make performance worse, but it all depends on how many rows you are gonna have vs how many other tables must be joined on this.